# How to cut part of SVG with css?

Tags: css, svg

I have a logo in SVG (minimal example):

```
<svg class="hide-text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 695 189.08">
    <path d="1....">
    <path d="2....">
    <path d="3....">
</svg>
```

I want to remove the text (logotype) from svg element when the `.hide-text` class is present.
Currently, I'm doing this with:

```css
.hide-text {
   path {
      &:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+10), &:last-child { /* paths for text part */
         display: none;
         /* visibility: hidden; */
         /* opacity: 0; */
         /* d: path('0') !important; */
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that all of them just "hide" the path & the parent SVG element is still taking space!
(`d` only works in Chrome & that's not good)

How can I remove some paths using CSS?

### Update

Here's a sample image to clarify the question:
[image]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 610.85 206.39">
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill:#1d1d1b;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>logotest</title>

    <path class="a" d="M367.19,678.65H327.13v-89H300.82V557.23h94.7v32.38H367.19Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>

    <path class="a" d="M404.22,557.23h76.9v30.36H444.29v15.17h32.17V631.9H444.29v16.39h36.83v30.36h-76.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>

    <path class="a" d="M541.21,644h-1.82l-12.34,34.61H486.17l23.68-62.13-21-59.29h43.7L541.82,592h1.42l10.32-34.81h38.85l-19.22,59.5,22.46,61.92h-42.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>

    <path class="a" d="M664.65,678.65H624.58v-89h-26.3V557.23H693v32.38H664.65Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>

    <path class="a" d="M208.52,472.67,106.81,502.89,82.13,606.09l77,73,101.71-30.22,24.69-103.2Zm19.36,144.92-58.15,17.28-44-41.73,14.12-59L198,516.86l44,41.73Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you'd like to achieve. Would you like to hide the `.hide-text` parent AND and texts in it? Please explain.

Comment: @azu I want to hide the paths that shape the text (paths 3~10 plus last one) when the parent SVG element has `.hide-text` class.

Comment: The ideal way to achieve this would be by modifying the `viewBox`, but unfortunately, viewBox is not a styleable property. It may be possible by tweaking `width`, `height`, and `preserveAspectRatio`. But it will depend on your logo design and your page layout.  Without seeing either of those, there is not much we can do to help. Consider updating your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I added an example image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

First, we change the SVG to have `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"`. In simple terms, this tells the browser to keep the left side of the SVG visible if we reduce the width of the SVG.

Then all we need to do is hide the text, and set the width and height to values that will cause the text part of the SVG to be cut off.  A square seems to work.  See class `.two`.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.hide-text .text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 610.85 206.39" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" class="one">
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill:#1d1d1b;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>logotest</title>

    <g class="text">
      <path class="a" d="M367.19,678.65H327.13v-89H300.82V557.23h94.7v32.38H367.19Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M404.22,557.23h76.9v30.36H444.29v15.17h32.17V631.9H444.29v16.39h36.83v30.36h-76.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M541.21,644h-1.82l-12.34,34.61H486.17l23.68-62.13-21-59.29h43.7L541.82,592h1.42l10.32-34.81h38.85l-19.22,59.5,22.46,61.92h-42.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M664.65,678.65H624.58v-89h-26.3V557.23H693v32.38H664.65Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
    </g>

    <path class="a" d="M208.52,472.67,106.81,502.89,82.13,606.09l77,73,101.71-30.22,24.69-103.2Zm19.36,144.92-58.15,17.28-44-41.73,14.12-59L198,516.86l44,41.73Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
</svg>



<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 610.85 206.39" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" class="two hide-text">
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill:#1d1d1b;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>logotest</title>

    <g class="text">
      <path class="a" d="M367.19,678.65H327.13v-89H300.82V557.23h94.7v32.38H367.19Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M404.22,557.23h76.9v30.36H444.29v15.17h32.17V631.9H444.29v16.39h36.83v30.36h-76.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M541.21,644h-1.82l-12.34,34.61H486.17l23.68-62.13-21-59.29h43.7L541.82,592h1.42l10.32-34.81h38.85l-19.22,59.5,22.46,61.92h-42.9Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
      <path class="a" d="M664.65,678.65H624.58v-89h-26.3V557.23H693v32.38H664.65Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
    </g>

    <path class="a" d="M208.52,472.67,106.81,502.89,82.13,606.09l77,73,101.71-30.22,24.69-103.2Zm19.36,144.92-58.15,17.28-44-41.73,14.12-59L198,516.86l44,41.73Z" transform="translate(-82.13 -472.67)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just remembered the `<g>` in SVG!

Answer (score 3):

Might be much simpler to load two logos (one with text and one without), and add a display: none to one of them based on the existence of the class. This will remove it from page unlike with visibility: hidden

```
<div class="hide-text container-div">
    <svg class="logo-text"></svg>
    <svg class="logo-no-text"></svg>
</div>

<style>
    .container-div:not(.hide-text) > .logo-no-text {
        display: none;
    }
    .container-div:not(.hide-text) > .logo-text {
        display: block;
    }
    .container-div.hide-text > .logo-text {
        display: none;
    }
    .container-div.hide-text > .logo-no-text {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That's the way I'd do it. The two `display: block;` rules are not required.

Comment: @MikePoole I know I just thought it might be more readable that way, doesn't leave out any assumptions :) If you can get away with less rules definitely go for it.

Comment: I prefer `<g>` over two separate `<svg>`s (like the one in the accepted answer), but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width/height of the SVG you can hide part of the SVG using a negative margin. In the example I have two SVG elements with the same content except that the last has the class name `.hide-text`.

So, if you know the dimensions and the portion that needs to be cut off you can use this technique.

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
}

.hide-text {
  margin: 0 0 -50px;
}

.hide-text rect:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
  <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="navy"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="orange" transform="translate(0 100)"/>
</svg>
<div>Text</div>
<hr/>
<svg class="hide-text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
  <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="navy"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="orange" transform="translate(0 100)"/>
</svg>
<div>Text</div>
```